# Render and partial view using a variable coming from each tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, partial-views

I have just started using Rails and not found a solution for this situation yet.

I have a view and I want separate some parts on partial view using render. Imagine that I have a library and some books. I want to create a specific view for each book.

View:

```
<% @library.books.each do |book| %> //each book has a name and price
   //some stuffs using book.name and book.price
   <%= render :partial => "prices/book_price", :locals => { :book=> book } %>
<% end %>
```

Partial View:

```
<div class='book_price'>
   <div class="form-group">
      <h1> <%= book.name %> </h1>
      <br>
      <span><%= book.price%></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

It will create one partial view for each book but my problem is that when I use the variable in my partial view I'm only getting the first element of book, it seems that I lost the reference of the position on the each loop. For example, the first book is "Harry Potter" and the second one is "The Lord of the Rings". It's printing always the "Harry Potter".

Note: When I put the tags of my partial view inside the main view it works normally.

Does anyone know the solution for this?

Comment: Can you verify whether `@library.books` contains different entries?

Answer (score 1):

Rails will do the loop for you

```
<%= render :partial => "prices/book_price", collection: @library.books %>
```